# List View Error in Android

Tags: android

This is my code , I am getting error in this line:

```
String[] opt = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MainActivity);
```

So, please check my code and say me how to solve the error in that line

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        String[] opt = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MainActivity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        ListAdapter la = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, opt);
        lv.setAdapter(la);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent firstIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            After1.class);
                    startActivity(firstIntent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent secondIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            After2.class);
                    startActivity(secondIntent);
                    break;

  default:
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: First of all move this code String[] opt = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MainActivity); after setContentView();

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: same error is repeating "array cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: @ChiragRaval - Its not mandatory..

Comment: array cannot be resolved or is not a field this is error which i'm getting

Comment: other wise can any one just give me a source code of listview which consists of total 10 items and when ever i click on an item it should take me to the another screen please can any one help me

Comment: In which file you have declared `MainActivity array`??

Comment: i did not understand what ur asking

Comment: @user1920421- you needed example see my answer below

Comment: You are getting this error because there is no any resource like, `R.array.MainActivity`. In your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you needed example you can follow this one:

```
   import android.app.ListActivity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.ListView;
      import android.widget.TextView;
      import android.widget.Toast;
      import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
  public class ListFruitActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
        "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // no more this
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit,FRUITS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //here instead of showing toast message you can start new activity using intent 


        }
    });

}

}
```

to start new activity

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
```

here are some tutorials that can help you

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Comment: Unexpectedly stoped this is the error i'm getting wid ur code when i'm trying to run it

Comment: i have added imported packages if you didn't add in your activity and also given you some tutorial at the end of answer follow them

Answer (score 0):

R.array will de defined only when you will add an string-array in string.xml . so do that first them refer it using R.array.array_name

**string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>    <string-array        name="string_array_name">        <item            >text_string</item>    </string-array></resources>
```

**in Activity**

getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name);